# What are nested types?

Tags: java

I quote from the [JLS 9.1.1.2 strictfp Interfaces](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html)

"The effect of the `strictfp` modifier is to make all `float` or `double` expressions within the interface declaration be explicitly *FP-strict*. This implies that all **nested types** declared in the interface are implicitly `strictfp`."

So, what are nested types? Does it actually means nested reference types?

**UPDATE:**

I meant, I need a definition of *nested types*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested class is one declared inside another class, like this.

```
class SomeClass {
    class Nested {

    }
    static class StaticNested {

    }

}
```

You can also nest inside interfaces:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    class Nested {

    }
    static class StaticNested {

    }

}
```

The implication of this in terms of your question is if you do this:

```
strictfp interface SomeInterface {
```

or

```
strictfp class SomeClass {
```

Then when you have something inside

```
    class Nested {
```

It is implicitly

```
    strictfp class Nested {
```

Answer (score 2):

An interface can have nested interface inside its definition. It implies that when you place strictfp on the interface all the nested interfaces are also strictfp.

Note: Given many JVM are strictfp by default for almost all operations, it may be hard to tell the difference.